# Laravel will not add "colour" to column in database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

This is my routes folder and I will post the database beneath it, this problem is driving me insane, I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
Route::post('/addAssignment', function() {
    $title = Input::get('assignment_title');
    $context = Input::get('assignment_context');
    $day = Input::get('day');
    $month = Input::get('month');
    $year = Input::get('year');
    $subject = Input::get('subject');

    $colour = DB::table('class')->where('className', $subject)->value('classColour');

    DB::table('assignments')->insert(array(
        'assignments_title' => $title,
        'assignments_context' => $context,
        'assignments_due_day' => $day,
        'assignments_due_month' => $month,
        'assignments_due_year' => $year,
        'assignments_subject' => $subject,
        'assignments_colour' => $colour ? : 'lightblue'
        ));

    return Redirect::to('/assignments');
});
```

[image: 'class' database]

I'm creating `lightblue` as the default value if the colour isn't sent through, and it's always `lightblue`, I don't know why, this is a snippet of the assignments database.

[image]

So the information is going through, but why isn't it the right colour from the class table? Is `Input::get()` not treatable as a string? Thank you in advance, any help is much appreciated.

UPDATED:
This is the form I'm using for adding an assignment.

```
@section('ModalBody')


    {!! Form::open(array("url" => 'addAssignment', "method" => 'post')) !!}
    {!! Form::select('subject', $sub) !!}

    {!! Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31, array('style'=>'width:50px;display:inline')) !!}
    {!! Form::selectMonth('month', array('style'=>'width:50px;display:inline')) !!}
    {!! Form::selectYear('year', 2015, 2100, array('style'=>'width:50px;display:inline')) !!}

    {!! Form::text('assignment_title', null, array('style' => 'width:80%', 'placeholder' => 'Title' )) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('assignment_context', null, array('style' => 'width:80%;height:50px', 'placeholder' => 'Description' )) !!}

    {!! Form::submit("Add", array('class' => 'butn')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}


@stop
```

And this is the loop from the view source page

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="5AeOlqnhanrNnTYU572FyNzTG475zS0CiuQn4xL9">
<select name="subject"><option value="0">Mathematics</option>
<option value="1">Chemistry</option>
<option value="2">Mathematics Extension 1</option>
<option value="3">Mathematics Extension 2</option>
<option value="4">Physics</option>
<option value="5">French</option></select>
```

Comment: did you check `dd($colour);` is working correctly? whats this output?

Comment: It returned an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post comments yet. So, before this line:

```
$colour = DB::table('class')->where('className', $subject)->value('classColour');
```

Can you

```
echo $subject;
exit;
```

What do you get?

Edit:

As per our discussion, change:

```
$subjectName = DB::table('class')->where('class_active', '1')->lists('className');
```

to

```
$subjectName = DB::table('class')->where('class_active', '1')->lists('className', 'className');
```

Comment: I get '0', which probably means that I've been trying to look for a class with the name '0'... doesn't it?

Comment: Actually... You select the subject from a select dropdown 
`  {!! Form::select('subject', $sub) !!}`
And I think, it's just getting the nth term key, instead of the value, how do I check this?

Comment: View the source of the page where you make that select and see what the value is.

Comment: Seems as if they just loop the number of items and assign each value in descending order. I tried to find a way to set the value of each option to it's  name but I don't how to do that, do you?

Comment: Can you update your original post with the loop and the form?

Comment: Can you find out where $sub is coming from and post that, too? We need to alter what $sub looks like.

Comment: sub is coming from this `$subjectName = DB::table('class')->where('class_active', '1')->lists('className');`

Comment: May I just say, you were an absolute amazing help, and I'd like to thank you, very very much. This has been killing me for the last day, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may have some issue in below line

```
 $colour = DB::table('class')->where('className', $subject)->value('classColour');
```

replace that with

```
$exists_color = DB::table('class')->where('className', $subject)->first();
$colour = $exists_color ? $exists_color->classColour : 'lightblue';
```

```
DB::table('assignments')->insert(array(
    'assignments_title' => $title,
    'assignments_context' => $context,
    'assignments_due_day' => $day,
    'assignments_due_month' => $month,
    'assignments_due_year' => $year,
    'assignments_subject' => $subject,
    'assignments_colour' => $colour
));
```

Comment: I did and now I get this error 

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'assignments_colour' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `assignments` (`assignments_title`, `assignments_context`, `assignments_due_day`, `assignments_due_month`, `assignments_due_year`, `assignments_subject`, `assignments_colour`) values (Maths test, Hello, 1, 1, 2015, 0, ))

Comment: seems like you didn't change this line `$colour = $exists_color ? $exists_color->classColour : 'lightblue';`

Comment: Now it just prints out the lightblue, I don't understand why it is null when there is definitely a row with the same text,

Comment: `{!! $sub[$subject[$i]] !!}` does, and that's working completely fine, which it wasn't earlier but it does now thankfully, but now the colours just won't work

Comment: So you want to say $colour = DB::table('class')->where('className', $subject)->value('classColour'); line is not returning anything??? @sammourac

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, and I do not know why, It should just be a simple thing

Comment: Are you returning the text from the dropdown you select for subject or the values are like 0,1,2? most probably you are not returning the text value rather 0,1,2 etc. Can you just add your view from where you are inputting the value subject???? @sammourac

Comment: Yes me and IllegalPigeon figured that out not so long ago, i updated my question to show you whats happening